# Web Scraping to CSV - ValueError Could not broadcast input array from shape (2) into shape (1)

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I've been playing around with python and beautifulsoup last few days.  I've taken to trying to scrape a local gun advertising platform.

I've been on and got help and its been great.  with those help stages ive pushed to the next "right so how do i go about doing this...."

This is where i am at the moment:

I'm exporting (failing to) my data to csv.

I'm getting the error - ValueError - Could not broadcast input array from shape (2) into shape (1).

Some reading suggests im pulling in a 2d array into a 1d array? - looking at my code i cant see where i could be possibly doing this?

Would anyone mind having a scan and seeing where im going wrong?

Thanks!

full script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import urllib.request
import csv
import pandas
from pandas import DataFrame
import re

#csv creation
with open('Guntrader_Dealer.csv', mode='w') as csv_file:
fieldnames = ['Title', 'Make', 'Model', 'Licence', 'Orientation', 'Barrel Length', 'Stock Length', 'Chokes', 'Origin', 'Trigger', 'Ejection', 'Scope', 'Serial No', 'Stock No', 'Condition', 'Description', 'Price']
writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
writer.writeheader()

#all links list
all_links=[]

#grab all links which contain the href specifed
url="https://www.guntrader.uk/dealers/minsterley/minsterley-ranges/guns?page={}"
for page in range(1,3):
 res=requests.get(url).text
 soup=BeautifulSoup(res,'html.parser')
 for link in soup.select('a[href*="dealers/minsterley/minsterley-ranges/guns/"]'):
  all_links.append("https://www.guntrader.uk" + link['href'])

for a_link in all_links:

#Defining the span text in GunDetails lookups
    def make_span(make):
       return make.name=='span' and 'Make:' in make.parent.contents[0]    
    def model_span(model):
       return model.name=='span' and 'Model:' in model.parent.contents[0]
    def licence_span(licence):
       return licence.name=='span' and 'Licence:' in licence.parent.contents[0]
    def orient_span(orient):
       return orient.name=='span' and 'Orient.:' in orient.parent.contents[0]    
    def barrel_span(barrel):
      return barrel.name=='span' and 'Barrel:' in barrel.parent.contents[0]
    def stock_span(stock):
      return stock.name=='span' and 'Stock:' in stock.parent.contents[0]    
    def choke_span(choke):
      return choke.name=='span' and 'Chokes:' in choke.parent.contents[0]
    def origin_span(origin):
      return origin.name=='span' and 'Origin:' in origin.parent.contents[0]
    def trigger_span(trigger):
      return trigger.name=='span' and 'Trigger:' in trigger.parent.contents[0]
    def ejection_span(ejection):
      return ejection.name=='span' and 'Ejection:' in ejection.parent.contents[0]
    def serial_span(serial):
      return serial.name=='span' and 'Serial #:' in serial.parent.contents[0]
    def stockno_span(stockno):
      return stockno.name=='span' and 'Stock #:' in stockno.parent.contents[0]
    def condition_span(condition):
      return condition.name=='span' and 'Condition:' in condition.parent.contents[0]
    def scope_span(scope):
      return scope.name=='span' and 'Scope:' in scope.parent.contents[0]

    res = urllib.request.urlopen(a_link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res, 'html.parser')

#soup searches using the define criteria

    makes = soup.find(make_span)
    gun_makes = makes.content if makes else 'none'
    models = soup.find(model_span)
    gun_models = models.contents if models else 'none'
    licences = soup.find(licence_span)
    gun_licences = licences.contents if licences else 'none'
    orients = soup.find(orient_span)
    gun_orients = orients.contents if orients else 'none'    
    barrels = soup.find(barrel_span)
    gun_barrels = barrels.contents if barrels else 'none'
    stocks = soup.find(stock_span)
    gun_stocks = stocks.contents if stocks else 'none'
    chokes = soup.find(choke_span)
    gun_chokes = chokes.contents if chokes else 'none'
    origins = soup.find(origin_span)
    gun_origins = origins.contents if origins else 'none'
    triggers = soup.find(trigger_span)
    gun_triggers = triggers.contents if triggers else 'none'
    ejections = soup.find(ejection_span)
    gun_ejections = ejections.contents if ejections else 'none'
    scopes = soup.find(scope_span)
    gun_scopes = scopes.contents if scopes else 'none'
    serials = soup.find(serial_span)
    gun_serials = serials.contents if serials else 'none'
    stocknos = soup.find(stockno_span)
    gun_stocknos = stocknos.contents if stocknos else 'none'
    conditions = soup.find(condition_span)
    gun_conditions = conditions.contents if conditions else 'none'

#title price and description
    title = soup.select_one('h1[itemprop="name"]')
    gun_title = title.text if title else 'none'
    price = soup.select_one('p.price')
    gun_price = price.text if price else 'none'
    description = soup.select_one('p[itemprop="description"]')
    gun_description = description.text if description else 'none'


    data = { 'Title': gun_title, 'Make': gun_makes, 'Model': gun_models, 'Licence': gun_licences, 'Orientation': gun_orients, 'Barrel Length': gun_barrels, 'Stock Length': gun_stocks, 'Chokes': gun_chokes, 'Origin': gun_origins, 'Trigger': gun_triggers, 'Ejection': gun_ejections, 'Scope': gun_scopes, 'Serial No': gun_serials, 'Stock No': gun_stocknos, 'Condition': gun_conditions, 'Description': gun_description, 'Price': gun_price}

    df = DataFrame(data, columns = ['Title', 'Make', 'Model', 'Licence', 'Orientation', 'Barrel Length', 'Stock Length', 'Chokes', 'Origin', 'Trigger', 'Ejection', 'Scope', 'Serial No', 'Stock No', 'Condition', 'Description', 'Price'], index=[0])

    df.to_csv(r'Guntrader_Dealer.csv')
```

Comment: The problem seems to be in `gun_price` which is a list of lenght 2. You are trying to fit that into a single column in your DataFrame which doesn't work.

Comment: thanks for pointing that error out.  I've updated the gun_price to gun_price = price.text if price else 'none'.  Problem now is it runs, but isnt populating the csv. watching the byte content you would nearly suspect its constantly updating the first row rather than cycling through and putting data in each row?

Comment: Try `df.to_csv(r'Guntrader_Dealer.csv', mode='a')`

Comment: think thats it now @PetrNovotný see the file size 13kb and growing - just for reference - you wouldnt happen to know what the mode=a,w,wb etc mean? - i assumed w = write?, wb = write binary?

Comment: The mode refers to the write mode. In Python, files can be [opened](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) in different modes. There is `'r'` = read, `'w'` = write, `'a'` = append. There's also `'rb'` and '`wb'` for binary and [more](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've wrote down the script for you. Instead of overwriting different df's to same file, I've created main df which appends all df's in for loop.

Here is the final code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv
import pandas
from pandas import DataFrame
import re
import os
import locale
os.environ["PYTHONIOENCODING"] = "utf-8"


#csv creation
with open('Guntrader_Dealer.csv', mode='w') as csv_file:
    fieldnames = ['Title', 'Make', 'Model', 'Licence', 'Orientation', 'Barrel Length', 'Stock Length', 'Chokes', 'Origin', 'Trigger', 'Ejection', 'Scope', 'Serial No', 'Stock No', 'Condition', 'Description', 'Price']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()

all_links=[]

#grab all links which contain the href specifed
url="https://www.guntrader.uk/dealers/minsterley/minsterley-ranges/guns?page={}"
for page in range(1,3):
    res=requests.get(url).text
    soup=BeautifulSoup(res,'html.parser')
    for link in soup.select('a[href*="dealers/minsterley/minsterley-ranges/guns/"]'):
        all_links.append("https://www.guntrader.uk" + link['href'])

df_main = DataFrame(columns = ['Title', 'Make', 'Model', 'Licence', 'Orientation', 'Barrel Length', 'Stock Length', 'Chokes', 'Origin', 'Trigger', 'Ejection', 'Scope', 'Serial No', 'Stock No', 'Condition', 'Description', 'Price'])

for a_link in all_links:
    def make_span(make):
       return make.name=='span' and 'Make:' in make.parent.contents[0]    
    def model_span(model):
       return model.name=='span' and 'Model:' in model.parent.contents[0]
    def licence_span(licence):
       return licence.name=='span' and 'Licence:' in licence.parent.contents[0]
    def orient_span(orient):
       return orient.name=='span' and 'Orient.:' in orient.parent.contents[0]    
    def barrel_span(barrel):
      return barrel.name=='span' and 'Barrel:' in barrel.parent.contents[0]
    def stock_span(stock):
      return stock.name=='span' and 'Stock:' in stock.parent.contents[0]    
    def choke_span(choke):
      return choke.name=='span' and 'Chokes:' in choke.parent.contents[0]
    def origin_span(origin):
      return origin.name=='span' and 'Origin:' in origin.parent.contents[0]
    def trigger_span(trigger):
      return trigger.name=='span' and 'Trigger:' in trigger.parent.contents[0]
    def ejection_span(ejection):
      return ejection.name=='span' and 'Ejection:' in ejection.parent.contents[0]
    def serial_span(serial):
      return serial.name=='span' and 'Serial #:' in serial.parent.contents[0]
    def stockno_span(stockno):
      return stockno.name=='span' and 'Stock #:' in stockno.parent.contents[0]
    def condition_span(condition):
      return condition.name=='span' and 'Condition:' in condition.parent.contents[0]
    def scope_span(scope):
      return scope.name=='span' and 'Scope:' in scope.parent.contents[0]

    res = requests.get(a_link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')

    makes = soup.find(make_span)
    gun_makes = makes.content if makes else 'none'
    models = soup.find(model_span)
    gun_models = models.contents if models else 'none'
    licences = soup.find(licence_span)
    gun_licences = licences.contents if licences else 'none'
    orients = soup.find(orient_span)
    gun_orients = orients.contents if orients else 'none'    
    barrels = soup.find(barrel_span)
    gun_barrels = barrels.contents if barrels else 'none'
    stocks = soup.find(stock_span)
    gun_stocks = stocks.contents if stocks else 'none'
    chokes = soup.find(choke_span)
    gun_chokes = chokes.contents if chokes else 'none'
    origins = soup.find(origin_span)
    gun_origins = origins.contents if origins else 'none'
    triggers = soup.find(trigger_span)
    gun_triggers = triggers.contents if triggers else 'none'
    ejections = soup.find(ejection_span)
    gun_ejections = ejections.contents if ejections else 'none'
    scopes = soup.find(scope_span)
    gun_scopes = scopes.contents if scopes else 'none'
    serials = soup.find(serial_span)
    gun_serials = serials.contents if serials else 'none'
    stocknos = soup.find(stockno_span)
    gun_stocknos = stocknos.contents if stocknos else 'none'
    conditions = soup.find(condition_span)
    gun_conditions = conditions.contents if conditions else 'none'

    title = soup.select_one('h1[itemprop="name"]')
    gun_title = title.text if title else 'none'
    price = soup.select_one('p.price')
    gun_price = price.text if price else 'none'
    description = soup.select_one('p[itemprop="description"]')
    gun_description = description.text if description else 'none'


    data = { 'Title': gun_title, 'Make': gun_makes, 'Model': gun_models, 'Licence': gun_licences, 'Orientation': gun_orients, 'Barrel Length': gun_barrels, 'Stock Length': gun_stocks, 'Chokes': gun_chokes, 'Origin': gun_origins, 'Trigger': gun_triggers, 'Ejection': gun_ejections, 'Scope': gun_scopes, 'Serial No': gun_serials, 'Stock No': gun_stocknos, 'Condition': gun_conditions, 'Description': gun_description, 'Price': gun_price}

    df = DataFrame(data, columns = ['Title', 'Make', 'Model', 'Licence', 'Orientation', 'Barrel Length', 'Stock Length', 'Chokes', 'Origin', 'Trigger', 'Ejection', 'Scope', 'Serial No', 'Stock No', 'Condition', 'Description', 'Price'], index=[0])
    df_main = df_main.append(df, ignore_index = True)
df_main.to_csv('Guntrader_Dealer.csv', encoding='UTF-8')
```

Comment: absolute hero! was just looking into how to sort this out so cheers, was just starting to annoy me. fair play to ya! was a few placements i thought werent right causing all the titles etc to be constantly input into the csv with the other data too (guess was cause it was the final csv data was in the for loop) but can see was a few other tricks required. ta!

Comment: EkremGurdal - any idea why its not grabbing the make but grabs everything else?

Comment: gun_makes = makes.content if makes else 'none' > gun_makes = makes.contents if makes else 'none' spotted it